# Issue when updating triple with blank nodes using sqarql

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs, graphdb, blank-nodes

- This is my query, this query works fine for nodes with no blank node
  but the issue with arrives while updating with blank node

  **here those nodes get repeated 100 times after updating**

```
    DELETE {
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah schema:description ?o_0 .
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah it:hasArea ?o_1 .
    ?o_1 rdf:type ?o_1_0 .  ?o_1 schema:unitCode ?o_1_1 .
    ?o_1 schema:value ?o_1_2 .  ?o_1 schema:unitText ?o_1_3 .
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah it:unresolvedWikidataType ?o_2 .
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah schema:longitude ?o_3 .
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah schema:addressCountry ?o_4 .
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah rdfs:label ?o_5 .
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah rdf:type ?o_6 .
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah schema:url ?o_7 .
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah it:wikiLink ?o_8 .
 }
    INSERT {
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah  schema:description 'city and capital of Bali, Indonesia' . 
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah  it:hasArea _:bQRrRFzX1zv9qUGWy . 
    _:bQRrRFzX1zv9qUGWy  rdf:type schema:QuantitativeValue; 
    schema:unitCode 'KMK'; 
    schema:value '123.98'; 
    schema:unitText 'km²' . 
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah  it:unresolvedWikidataType 'Q3199141', 'Q13220204' . 
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah  schema:longitude '115.21666666667' . 
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah  schema:addressCountry it:WtC49aYLe8s0lsFC . 
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah  rdfs:label 'Denpasar' . 
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah  rdf:type schema:City . 
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah  schema:url <http://www.denpasarkota.go.id/> . 
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah  it:wikiLink <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denpasar> .
     }
     WHERE {
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah ?p ?o .
    OPTIONAL {  it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah schema:description ?o_0 }
    OPTIONAL {  it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah it:hasArea ?o_1 }
    OPTIONAL {  ?o_1 rdf:type ?o_1_0 }
    OPTIONAL {  ?o_1 schema:unitCode ?o_1_1 }
    OPTIONAL {  ?o_1 schema:value ?o_1_2 }
    OPTIONAL {  ?o_1 schema:unitText ?o_1_3 }
    OPTIONAL {  it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah it:unresolvedWikidataType ?o_2 }
    OPTIONAL {  it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah schema:longitude ?o_3 }
    OPTIONAL {  it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah schema:addressCountry ?o_4 }
    OPTIONAL {  it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah rdfs:label ?o_5 }
    OPTIONAL {  it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah rdf:type ?o_6 }
    OPTIONAL {  it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah schema:url ?o_7 }
    OPTIONAL {  it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah it:wikiLink ?o_8 }
 }
```

This is the output in json format,
and only **hasArea** which has blank node values is being repeated many times

```
"schema:latitude": [
  "-7.164444444444444"
],
"it:hasArea": [
  {
    "rdf:type": [
      "schema:QuantitativeValue"
    ],
    "schema:unitCode": [
      "KMK"
    ],
    "schema:value": [
      "392.47"
    ],
    "schema:unitText": [
      "km²"
    ]
  },
  {
    "rdf:type": [
      "schema:QuantitativeValue"
    ],
    "schema:unitCode": [
      "KMK"
    ],
    "schema:value": [
      "392.47"
    ],
    "schema:unitText": [
      "km²"
    ]
  },
  {
    "rdf:type": [
      "schema:QuantitativeValue"
    ],
    "schema:unitCode": [
      "KMK"
    ],
    "schema:value": [
      "392.47"
    ],
    "schema:unitText": [
      "km²"
    ]
  },...
],
"rdfs:label": [
  "Denpasar"
],
...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand - what is repeated? Can you show output please?

Comment: Also, you should run `DELETE {...} WHERE {...}` and `INSERT DATA {...}` as two separate SPARQL update statements if the data you're inserting is fixed as in your case.

Comment: using a blank node label in the `INSERT` part is not enough, this is document scoped but not across each binding of the `WHERE` part. If you want to do this, make the blank node stable in the `WHERE` part. Anyways, use `INSERT DATA` instead to avoid such pitfalls

Comment: I've update the optput, so the issue is only the blank node values here rdf:type, schema:unitCode, schema:value, schema:unitText  are only being update many times and i cannot figure out why

Comment: as I said, it is repeated as many time as the `WHERE` clause generates a binding - and although you use a label, internally a new blank node will be generated for each binding. Using a blank node label in the `INSERT` is not the way to go, you can set a fixed blank node in the `WHERE` part, just do `WHERE { BIND(_:bQRrRFzX1zv9qUGWy AS ?area_node)
    it:4D9AT21jAasfL9ah ?p ?o . ` and use this `area_node` variable in the `INSERT` part. Or as I also said, do `DELETE {} WHERE {}; INSERT DATA {}`

Comment: yes, binding blank node inside where works thanks